# A reply I made on my own post got deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

I posted a question to an issue I have. When someone offered help and asked a question about my machine, I replied to it, but that reply got pulled - with a message saying it didn't answer the original question.

Well, no it didn't. If I could solve the issue myself why would I post in the first place? Now, the user hasn't replied back, and I STILL have a problem with my computer.

Why was my comment deleted?

Comment: Comments are done in this box here, maybe you used the answer box?

Answer (score 10):

Well - from what I see on super user, which has its own meta - meta.superuser.com, you've posted multiple answers from multiple accounts instead of commenting (you can always comment on posts from the *same* account), which have been deleted.

You have 2 registered accounts, and one unregistered one in use from what I can tell [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1761302/no-sound-after-os-install-dummy-output/1761358#1761358)

Use the contact link at the bottom of any page and request your accounts merged, giving any information you can to assist the community team.